# Adding multiple subscripted characters in matplotlib axis labels using format

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I'm trying to add some subscripts to the y-label of a figure, and have it done using `format` so that I don't have to manualy make multiple figures. Since matplotlib allows for TeX formatting, this is quite easy, but the brackets for having multiple characters for sub- or superscript overlaps with `format`. The code I'm using is

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a,real_int, label='real int')
ax.plot(a,EM_int_sim, label='EM int')
ax.set_xlabel('t')
format_list = [l,j]
ax.set_ylabel(r"$\phi_{}$".format(*[l,j]))
ax.set_title("Offspring intensities")
ax.legend()
```

Normally in TeX formatting I'd use `\phi_{lj}` to write the characters, but `format` also uses the curly brackets. The above code only gives `l` in the subscript (which I expected), but I've also tried `\phi_{{}}` which doesn't give any characters, `\phi_{}{}` which only subscripts `l` but not `j` and `\phi_{}_{}` which gave the longes error message I've ever seen. Any ideas?

Comment: What is l and j? string variables or something more?

Comment: Nope, just integers (0 and 1 in this case)

Comment: And you just want the ylabel to read phi with subscript 0,1?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so if you switch your method for string insertion it works. Also i convert the list of ints you want to insert to a string to make it work. But you could also do multiple insertions into the curly brackets by doing different %s/%d/f..etc

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300)
ax.set_xlabel('t')
format_list = [0,1]

string_list=",".join([str(val) for val in format_list])

ax.set_ylabel(r"$\phi_{%s}$" % string_list)
ax.set_title("Offspring intensities")
ax.legend()
```